# Is there a way to modify the Solr query that gets generated by the Sitecore Content Search API before it gets sent to the search server?

Tags: content-search, solr

I'm looking to add some parameters to my Solr query that's not currently supported by the Search API (hit highlighting to be specific). Is there a way (like a pipeline processor or something) to intercept the query and modify it before it gets sent over to Solr?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your version there's a way to replace the component that writes the URL and makes the connection to Solr.  If you didn't feel like building out a Linq provider (and I don't recommend it), this could be a last resort hook into the process.

I was looking at this a little while ago as a candidate for adding support for Solr Cloud redirection and authenticated Solr endpoints, but I haven't completed that work yet.  I think some of these features are in the works at Sitecore now anyway.

The widget in question is wired in at:

```
<sitecore>
  <contentSearch>
    <indexConfigurations>
      <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.HttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet" />
    </indexConfigurations>
  </contentSearch>
</sitecore>
```